# matplotlib-SciencePlots package cannot run

Tags: python, matplotlib

i install SciencePlots packsge by `pip install SciencePlots`, and i have the following codes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('science') 

def model(x, p): 
   return x ** (2 * p + 1) / (1 + x ** (2 * p))
x = np.linspace(0.75, 1.25, 201)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for p in [10, 15, 20, 30, 50, 100]:      
    ax.plot(x, model(x, p), label=p)
ax.legend(title='Order')
ax.set(xlabel='Voltage (mV)')
ax.set(ylabel='Current ($\mu$A)')
ax.autoscale(tight=True)
fig.savefig('fig1.jpg', dpi=300)
```

but it results in an error，the error says：

```
OSError: 'science' not found in the style library and input is not a valid URL or path; see `style.available` for list of available styles
```

python version: 3.8.8

SciencePlots version: 1.0.1

matplotlib version: 3.3.4

numpy version: 1.19.2

i use Anaconda and Jupyter Notebook for python coding

Can anybody help to fix it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: As described in the official reference, you need to copy the installed style files to the style directory of matplotlib. See [this](https://pypi.org/project/SciencePlots/1.0.2/).

Answer (score 2):

I had been facing the same trouble as you. I managed to work it out by installing scienceplots package from the Github repo [SciencePlots](https://github.com/garrettj403/SciencePlots) by typing

`pip install SciencePlots` (For the latest release) or `pip install git+https://github.com/garrettj403/SciencePlots` (for the latest commit) into a Linux Terminal.

Since then I have been able to import 'science' style successfully.

Although in the Github repo it is recommended to `import scienceplots` into the notebook, but I actually tested my notebook without it and it worked just fine.

EDIT: Nonetheless, the command `plt.style.available` doesn't show `science` as an available style and I only get

```
['Solarize_Light2',
 '_classic_test_patch',
 '_mpl-gallery',
 '_mpl-gallery-nogrid',
 'bmh',
 'classic',
 'dark_background',
 'fast',
 'fivethirtyeight',
 'ggplot',
 'grayscale',
 'seaborn-v0_8',
 'seaborn-v0_8-bright',
 'seaborn-v0_8-colorblind',
 'seaborn-v0_8-dark',
 'seaborn-v0_8-dark-palette',
 'seaborn-v0_8-darkgrid',
 'seaborn-v0_8-deep',
 'seaborn-v0_8-muted',
 'seaborn-v0_8-notebook',
 'seaborn-v0_8-paper',
 'seaborn-v0_8-pastel',
 'seaborn-v0_8-poster',
 'seaborn-v0_8-talk',
 'seaborn-v0_8-ticks',
 'seaborn-v0_8-white',
 'seaborn-v0_8-whitegrid',
 'tableau-colorblind10']
```

as available styles.

Answer (score 1):

This answer requires SciencePlot:

`pip install SciencePlots`

SciencePlots are themes for the matplotlib library that match the style recommended by various popular academic journals.
https://github.com/garrettj403/SciencePlots

The function expects an iterable.

`plt.style.use(['science'])`

This allows you to overlap multiple styles

`plt.style.use(['science', 'notebook])`

Comment: ```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#plt.style.use(['science', 'notebook'])
plt.style.available
```
no such style even thought the example did have them:

['Solarize_Light2',
 '_classic_test_patch',
 '_mpl-gallery',

...

see https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.11-settings-and-stylesheets.html

https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/style_sheets/style_sheets_reference.html actually use the above listed style but not the one in the example.  There is no science or notebook style

Answer (score 1):

The style does not exist by default.  Instead it has to be installed here: https://github.com/garrettj403/SciencePlots

Otherwise if you check:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
#plt.style.use(['science', 'notebook'])
plt.style.available
```

no such style even thought the example did have them:

['Solarize_Light2',
'_classic_test_patch',
'_mpl-gallery',
...

There is no such style.

BTW the example did show you can use that science style if just one and if multiple then you have to use []

Answer (score 0):

Before updating new version, you need add this "import scienceplots" into you code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).